# put gridview in ajax update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I want to make my grid view updated its view without postback using ajax update panal how ?

for example when I press edit it is the grid updated without load the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something as below :

```
   <atlas:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <atlas:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView>
                    .....
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </atlas:UpdatePanel>
```